# MATLAB function for calculating the area of polygon using sum of triangle areas

Tags: matlab, function, defined

I have a question regarding a MATLAB function I have written.  It takes as input a set of x and y vertex coordinates in the form of two row vectors, and uses these to calculate the area of a polygon.

For the single triangle case it runs fine (although I KNOW my code could be made more efficient and to look better). However, I am to use this function in a script that takes a set of x and y points and calculates the perimeter and area of the polygon bounded by the coordinate points.

Using the function I created for the area of a triangle, the area of the polygon can be calculated based on these steps:

- there are N - 2 triangles (where N is the amount of sides to the polygon)
- my function calculates the area of these triangles 
  (using `A = 0.5(x1*(y2-y3)-x2*(y1-y3)+x3(y1-y2)`)
- sum the triangular areas to find the area of the polygon.

I have my code written below.  My perimeter function works very well, but I am not sure how to implement the area function for the triangle into the polygon area program.  **I believe that my formula is correct, and the problem lies somewhere in the loop indexing.**

Any suggestions on how to proceed from what I have below would be appreciated!

```
function [tri_area] = area2dd(coords_x,coords_y)

%%Input argument check
narginchk(2,2) ;

%%Calculation
% % ii = 1:length(coords_x)-2;
% % jj = 1:length(coords_y)-2;

if length(coords_x) == 3 
    ii = 1:length(coords_x) -2;
    jj = 1:length(coords_y) -2;
    tri_area = sum(abs(0.5.*(coords_x(ii).*(coords_y(jj+1)-21coords_y(jj+2))-coords_x(ii+1)... 
        .*(coords_y(jj)-coords_y(jj+2))+coords_x(ii+2).*(coords_y(jj)-23coords_y(jj+1)))))
else
    ii = 1:3:length(coords_x) -2;
    jj = 1:3:length(coords_y) -2;
    tri_area = sum(abs(0.5.*(coords_x(ii).*(coords_y(jj+1)-29coords_y(jj+2))-coords_x(ii+1)... 
       .*(coords_y(jj)-coords_y(jj+2))+coords_x(ii+2).*(coords_y(jj)-31coords_y(jj+1)))))
end
```

Comment: You may be looking for [`polyarea`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyarea.html)

Comment: I wish that was the case, unfortunately I have to write a function that calculates the polygon area based on the interior triangles.  I have seen several more efficient ways to do this, but my assignment says I must use this method.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem with your current code?

Comment: My problem lies within the else statement.  I want to calculate the areas of the triangles within the polygon given any amount of x and y coordinates.  I think my formula is correct.  I believe the problem lies somewhere in the loop indexing. I am not sure what to set the index to so that I can capture the points to use in the calculation for the areas.

Comment: Try to use the matlab debugger to understand your code better (and find your mistake)

Comment: Thanks, I got it.  I had the y1 coordinate increasing with the index when it should always have remained at its initial location throughout the calculation.  Thanks!

Comment: You may consider creating an answer yourself (and accept if after some days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for any interested parties or anyone else who might be solving a problem like mine I have the final WORKING code written below.  This function can do double duty.  If the coordinate vectors input are in 3 pairs then the function will calculate the area of a triangle.  If there are more than 3 sets of coordinate pairs then it will calculate the area of the polygon bounded by those coordinates.

```
narginchk(2,2) ;
if length(coords_x) == 3 
ii = 1
jj = 1
area = sum(abs(0.5.*(coords_x(ii).*(coords_y(jj+1)-coords_y(jj+2))- ...
coords_x(ii+1).*(coords_y(jj)-coords_y(jj+2))+coords_x(ii+2).*...       
(coords_y(jj)-coords_y(jj+1))))) ;
else
ii = 1:length(coords_x) -3 ;
jj = 1:length(coords_y) -3 ;
area = sum((abs(0.5.*(coords_x(1).*(coords_y(jj+1)-coords_y(jj+2)) ...
-coords_x(ii+1)... 
.*(coords_y(1)-coords_y(jj+2))+coords_x(ii+2).*(coords_y(1)- ...
coords_y(jj+1)))))) ;
end
end
```